# « Vous même[s|ø] » ? lorsqu’il s’agit d’un vouvoiement

Tags: adjectifs, accord, pluriel, vouvoiement

Normalement, les adjectifs ne s’accordent pas en nombre lorsqu’est utilisé un vouvoiement comme dans « Vous êtes beau ».

Mais qu’en est-il dans le cas de « Vous même*τ* » (où *τ* représente la terminaison qui peut possiblement être *s* ou rien) s’adressant à une unique personne ? Accorde-t-on *même* au pluriel ou non ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

« **Beau** » est un attribut du sujet, ici « **vous** ». Si ce sujet représente une personne unique que l'on vouvoie, on écrira « Vous êtes **beau** » et s'il s'agit de plusieurs personnes, ce sera « Vous êtes **beaux** » .

Avec « **vous-même** », on retrouve la même logique. En s'adressant à une seule personne :

> Vous ne le croyez pas ? Monsieur, vous l'avez dit **vous-même** il y a cinq minutes !

Et à un groupe :

> Permettez-moi de vous conduire à une table, à moins que vous ne préfériez en choisir une **vous-mêmes**.

Comment: Oui, c’est bien du « Vous du respect » autrement dit du vouvoiement dont il est question ici. Je ne parle pas du pluriel régulier.

Comment: @Fauve Alors, pas de s à la fin de *même*.

Comment: @LPH Merci ! Tu peux corriger ce type d'erreur dans mes réponses si tu veux.